# How do I obtain a dictionary from a list, with list entrys as key and the amount of the items in the list as value, using python?

Tags: python, list, dictionary

In a specific case I have this list:

```
[12112,7676,11708,6045,4705,11143,11143,5895]
```

and want this output:

```
{"12112":"1","7676":"1","11708":"1","11143":"2","5895":"1","6045":"1","4705":"1"}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `Counter`:

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> l = [12112,7676,11708,6045,4705,11143,11143,5895]
>>> Counter(l)
Counter({11143: 2, 4705: 1, 7676: 1, 5895: 1, 12112: 1, 11708: 1, 6045: 1})
```

And if you want a dict

```
>>> dict(Counter(l))
{12112: 1, 4705: 1, 11143: 2, 11708: 1, 5895: 1, 7676: 1, 6045: 1}
```

As your question use strings, a dict comprehension does the job:

```
>>> {str(i):str(j) for i,j in Counter(l).items()}
{'12112': '1', '11143': '2', '4705': '1', '11708': '1', '5895': '1', '6045': '1', '7676': '1'}
```

And since you want a string with `"`:

```
>>> re.sub(r'(\d+)',r'"\1"',str(dict(Counter(l))))
'{"12112": "1", "4705": "1", "11143": "2", "11708": "1", "5895": "1", "7676": "1", "6045": "1"}'
```

Comment: Nice. ty. Is there an easy way to make all keys and values to strings?

Comment: I specifically need " instead of '. I would use str({str(i):str(j) for i,j in Counter(l).items()}).replace("'",'"'). or is there a more elegant way?

Comment: @Akku `'a'` or `"a"` represent the same string: try `'a'=="a"`

Comment: print( [ (str(k),str(v)) for k, v in dict(Counter(a)).items() ] )

Comment: I know. But i need that string to be send via tcp and the other side does not seem to work right with 'a'.

Comment: @Akku Then I don't see a better way than yours.

Comment: You can also use a map to apply str on all the values u ve.

Comment: Could you give me an example for the map approach?

Answer (score 1):

You can make a `set` out of your list to determine the unique elements. Then use a dict comprehension with `count` to determine how many instances there are of each unique element in the list.

```
>>> l = [12112,7676,11708,6045,4705,11143,11143,5895]
>>> {i : l.count(i) for i in set(l)}
{12112: 1, 4705: 1, 5895: 1, 11708: 1, 11143: 2, 7676: 1, 6045: 1}
```

Otherwise you can just use `collections.Counter`

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> dict(Counter(l))
{12112: 1, 4705: 1, 5895: 1, 11708: 1, 11143: 2, 7676: 1, 6045: 1}
```

Comment: This is probably inefficient, since list.count is O(n)

Answer (score 1):

You can also do that using `groupby`

Convert all the numbers to strings using `map`

```
m= map(str,l)
```

then `groupby`, the length of every list describes the frequency.

```
m= map(str,l)
{key:str(len(list(group))) for key, group in groupby(m)}
```

Your code would look like

```
l = [12112,7676,11708,6045,4705,11143,11143,5895]
from itertools import groupby
print {key:str(len(list(group))) for key, group in groupby(map(str,l))}
```

Output:

```
{'12112': '1', '11143': '2', '4705': '1', '11708': '1', '5895': '1', '6045': '1', '7676': '1'}
```